# I'm trying to solve a problem " Time limit exceeded " using Python in Hackerearth

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, tree

I'm trying to solve HackerRank problem [Bomb Game](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/bomb-game-13ebde2d/?source=list_view):

> #### Problem
>
> You are playing a game in which you have a rectangular grid of * cells. Each cell is either empty or has a firework. Empty cells are marked with `"."`, cells with firework are marked with `"*"` . Two cells are said to be adjacent if they share a side.
>
> If firework in any cell explodes it destroys itself and the empty cells connected to it. Two cells are connected if there is a path of empty adjacent cells between them.
> You have to find the number of cells that will be destroyed if the fireworks are triggered independently.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> The first line contains an integer  denoting the dimensions of the grid.
> Each of the next  lines contains symbols: `"."` for empty cells, `"*"` for cells containing a firework.
> **Note:** All rows have  number of symbols.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> Print the sum of the number of cells destroyed if each bomb is triggered independently.
>
> **Input Constraints:**
>
> 1 ≤  ≤ 100
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 4
> *..*
> ..*.
> *..*
> *..*
> ```
>
> **Sample Output:** 66
>
> #### Explanation
>
> Here  = 4. So given grid  is of 4 x 4 size.
>
> Considering indexing starts from 1 in the grid:
>
> 1. A[1][1] has firework, so it will destroy all the 8 empty cells connected to it and including itself, it will destroy 9 cells in total.
> 2. A[1][4] has firework, so it will destroy all the 9 empty cells connected to it and including itself, it will destroy 10 cells in total.
> 3. [...]
>
> So total cells destroyed will be 9+10+10+9+10+9+9 = 66.

When I submit my solution it passes a few test cases, but if n >= 100 I get a message:

> Time limit exceeded

My code:

```
n = int(input())

grid = [input() for i in range(n)]

count = 0

def dfs(i, j):
    if i < 0 or i >= n or j < 0 or j >= n or visited[i][j] or grid[i][j] == "*":
        return 0
    visited[i][j] = True
    return 1 + dfs(i + 1, j) + dfs(i - 1, j) + dfs(i, j + 1) + dfs(i, j - 1)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if grid[i][j] == "*":
            visited = [[False for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
            count += dfs(i + 1, j) + dfs(i - 1, j) + dfs(i, j + 1) + dfs(i, j - 1) + 1
            
print(count)
```

How can I improve the code so it runs faster?

Comment: One small thing you can do is to replace `[False for _ in range(n)]` by `[False] * n`.

Comment: I guess you are getting `TLE` because of the nested `for-loops`. They are making your program `O(n**2)`. You can try `itertools-product`. I know there are some ways where you can traverse all the elements of `NXN` matrix in O(N) time.

Comment: A more efficient but more complicated approach is to identify "islands" of empty cells (empty cells connected to each other) and their size. After that you only have to check for each fireworks cell to which islands it is connected and sum the size of these islands.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the scenario, where the n by n grid is mostly empty, and you have n fireworks at the bottom row. The program will count the same n*(n-1) area of the grid n times for each firework.

A more efficient approach would be to count the empty areas first, then add together the results multiplied by the fireworks on the borders of the areas.

Modify the dfs search so it starts from an empty cell, not from a firework. Have a root dfs function, and a recursive one. The recursive dfs will be just like yours, with the addition that if it finds a firework, it adds its position to a set, something like:

```
def dfs(i, j):
    if i < 0 or i >= n or j < 0 or j >= n or visited[i][j]:
        return 0
    if grid[i][j] == "*":
        fireworks.add((i, j))
        return 0
    visited[i][j] = True
    return 1 + dfs(i + 1, j) + dfs(i - 1, j) + dfs(i, j + 1) + dfs(i, j - 1)
```

In the root dfs function, count the empty area, and multiply it with the number of fireworks found:

```
def root_dfs(i, j):
    area_count = dfs(i, j)
    count += area_count * len(fireworks)
    fireworks = {}
```

Now you can iterate the grid in the main loop, and if you find an empty cell that is not visited, run the root_dfs function.

This method counts every cell once, thus impoving the complexity of the algorithm, but it is still not ideal. It still iterates over the grid in the main loop, and encounters many already visited cells. It can be further improved if in root_dfs you loop through the found fireworks, and find all empty cells that are readchable from the current firework on a route that only contains fireworks in between its endpoints. Add the found empty cells to a queue. Restart the root_bfs from the first element of the queue, and continue until there are no empty cells left.

**Disclaimer**: I do not have an account on the site, so i didn't test the code, it is only to explain the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is performing a `dfs` flood-fill algorithm on the same area of cells over and over again, just starting from different starting cells.

Instead you should try to only visit cells once, starting from an unvisited, empty cell, and identify the *distinct* areas. For each such area identify its size, and mark each visited cell with the id of the area it belongs to. Then iterate the fireworks cells and see which distinct areas it touches so that you can accumulate the count.

An another note: a recursive DFS algorithm may quickly consume the available call stack. For larger inputs this may be a problem. Consider using an algorithm that doesn't use recursion.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
from collections import deque 

def solve(grid):
    n = len(grid)
    # We will mark a visited cell with the id of the area it belongs to: 0 means it is not visited yet
    visited = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
    # Keep track of the size of each distinct area
    areaSizes = [0]  # area 0 represents off-grid cells: there are 0 of them

    def bfs(i, j, areaId):
        size = 0
        q = deque()
        q.append((i, j))
        while q:
            i, j = q.popleft()
            if 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < n and visited[i][j] == 0 and grid[i][j] != "*":
                size += 1
                visited[i][j] = areaId  # Mark cell with the id of the distinct area this cell belongs to
                q.append((i-1, j))
                q.append((i+1, j))
                q.append((i, j-1))
                q.append((i, j+1))

        return size

    # Function to get the id of the area that a cell belongs to
    def area(i, j):
        if i < 0 or i >= n or j < 0 or j >= n or grid[i][j] == "*":
            return 0
        return visited[i][j]

    # Collect the sizes of all distinct areas, and mark visited cells with the id of the area they are in
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if visited[i][j] == 0:
                areaSizes.append(bfs(i, j, len(areaSizes)))
    # Check the area(s) which each firework touches and accumulate the count            
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if grid[i][j] == "*":
                touchingAreas = set(  # Only collect an area's id once
                    (area(i + 1, j), area(i - 1, j), area(i, j + 1), area(i, j - 1))
                )
                count += 1 + sum(areaSizes[areaId] for areaId in touchingAreas)
    return count

n = int(input())
grid = [input() for i in range(n)]
print(solve(grid))
```